Difference in Memory Usage Between malloc and new in C++
I'm observing a difference in the total memory allocation when using malloc versus new in a simple C++ program, as reported by Valgrind. Below are the two versions of my program and the corresponding Valgrind outputs.
Version using malloc:
#include <cstdlib>
int main() {
    int* a = (int *)malloc(4);
    return 0;
}

Valgrind output for malloc:
==34673== HEAP SUMMARY:
==34673==     in use at exit: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==34673==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 4 bytes allocated

Version using new:
int main() {
    int* a = new int;
    return 0;
}

Valgrind output for new:
==35295== HEAP SUMMARY:
==35295==     in use at exit: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==35295==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 72,708 bytes allocated

I'm confused about why there's such a significant difference in the "total heap usage" reported for these two cases. Specifically, why does the new version report much more bytes allocated compared to the malloc version? Does this have to do with how C++ handles memory management internally when using new?
Also, there is 72,704B overhead even if I only use this code:
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    return 0;
}

It seems that this overhead has something to do with dynamic memory management, but I don't understand why it's so significant.
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

valgrind --version
valgrind-3.18.1

command I used to build g++ program_name.cpp and then valgrind ./a.out

These are two nearly unrelated questions, and shouldn't be combined in one. Get rid of the second question, and ask it separately if you like (but you'll need to include more information, because you should see this memory usage, but optimizers might be eliminating it in certain predictable cases.

its overhead from iosteam. cout and friends are objects so there is state and thus memory associated to them.

@ShadowRanger Do you need me to provide more information?

@NathanOliver I agree, but if you look at the version using new that I provided in the question, you'd see that it's the exact same amount of overhead as including . 72,708 - 4 = 72,704. That's interesting. I'm looking for the reason for that.

It can throw, can touch cerr and cause iostream initialization. This is implementation details.

@sajad new most likely is bringing in parts of the standard library including iostream

@sajad new definitely will bring in throw and code dealing with this, since a failure with new throws a std::bad_alloc exception.  A call to malloc does not do this, as all it does is return a null on failure.

Looks like library overhead.

According to ISO C Standard (ISO/IEC 9899), 7.22.3 Memory management functions, paragraph 1 and 7.22.3.4 The malloc function, description:

The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated)... The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and whose value is indeterminate.

The malloc function is a simple C function that allocates a block of memory of the specified size and returns a pointer to it. So, in the version of your program using malloc, the malloc function is asked to allocate 4 bytes.
According to ISO C++ Standard (ISO/IEC 14882), 5.3.4 New, paragraph 10:

A new-expression passes the amount of space requested to the allocation function as the first argument of type std::size_t. That argument shall be no less than the size of the object being created; it may be greater than the size of the object being created only if the object is an array. For arrays of char and unsigned char, the difference between the result of the new-expression and the address returned by the allocation function shall be an integral multiple of the strictest fundamental alignment requirement (3.11) of any object type whose size is no greater than the size of the array being created.

new is an operator, not just a function. It has more responsibilities compared to malloc.  Since it not only allocates the memory, but it also calls the constructor for objects. So, in the version of your program using new, the actual memory allocation by new can involve more than just the 4 bytes requested for an int.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
